# mysqldump stops at 4GB

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to dump a MySQL (5.7) database of a about 150 GB, out of which most data (about 90 GB) is in a single table. I tried using MySQL Workbench (6.3) to do this through the GUI. The process starts, and most tables finish, but the big ones eventually fail.

I got recommended to use the commandline tool mysqldump.exe instead, and I tried that. This seems to work, but also eventually fails on the big tables, and reports:

```
mysqldump: Got Errno 28 on write
```

I'm trying to dump to an external drive with plenty of space.

One curious thing, is the failure always seems to happen exactly when the file in question hits 4 GB (or 3,99GB). I've tried looking around for this, but no luck!

I'm running Windows 10, 64-bit, mysqldump is 64-bit, I have 16 GB of RAM in the system. I don't feel like I should hit any 4 GB limits, but I'm probably missing something very basic?

Hope you guys can help me out!

The command in running to do the dump looks like this:

`mysqldump -t -u root -p [database] [table] > J:\table_name.sql`

Comment: What is the filesystem? The file size limit for FAT32 is 4Gb

Comment: I feel like and idiot, thank you :) Going to fix this, and see if it works! It most likely does.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ, You where right :) The workbench GUI also works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: FYI: MySQL Workbench under the hood also uses mysqldump, so it makes no difference if you use WB or mysqldump in a terminal.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case, I just saw somewhere someone recommend trying to go around workbench :) But thanks for the heads-up! The more you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size limit for a FAT32 filesystem is 4 Gigabytes. You will be hitting this limit.

Comment: This turned out to be the problem! Changed the file system, and now it works wonderfully!